# Zxing Android app

Tags: android, zxing

This is purely pertaining to the Zxing android app. I downloaded the source code of the zxing 1.7. There were lot of folders inside the zip file. There was one folder named android, so I assumed it has to be with android app. I imported the source code to eclipse and added the core.jar as a library.

The build was successfull and the bar code scanner worked correctly and returned the product code...BUT there was one thing that was missing. after the identification of product code there would be product identification step where the product code would be deduced as "Hair Spray" etc and another box would be displaying with that information and asking us whether we accept this or not. I AM NOT GETTING THIS AT ALL. After the product bar code is identified that'sit the app does not progress.....

Have I missed some code import.....Please advice

To PUT THIS MORE SIMPLY>>>BARCODE IS IDENTIFIED BUT PRODUCT NAME IS NOT RESOLVED.

Comment: It doesnt say it is hairspray, it just gives the result(string), u have to check the resultant string and add conditions(or what ever) to tell whether it is hairspray or not

Answer (score 0):

Do not import `android/`, you do not need it for your app, and there are reasons you do not want to be copying all of that.

The Barcode Scanner app does no such thing that you are expecting. It scans barcodes, and that is it.